# Post selection on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms

I want to perform post-selection on IBM Qiskit and run on actual quantum computer.
([What is post-selection](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-postselection-in-quantum-computing/1675#1675))
How can I perform it ?

Can I use qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.reset for it ? How to use it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiskit is used to have `get_subsystems_counts` function which takes `complete_system_counts` and returns the counts subject to a post selection specified using `post_select_index` and `post_select_flag` parameters.

```
complete_system_counts = { '10 1': 255, '11 0':320, '01 1': 449 }
result = get_subsystems_counts(complete_system_counts, 1, '1')
print(result)
```

However, since `get_subsystems_counts` is part of Qiskit Aqua, it is now deprecated. I'm not aware of any alternative, but you can get its code from [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/stable/0.9/qiskit/aqua/utils/subsystem.py#L65).

Comment: Any alternative ways to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Postselection isn't a gate. You can't apply it on an actual quantum computer.

What you can do is take many unpostselected samples and discard the ones that didn't meet the selection criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what methods to use to perform it on Qiskit ?